# Vim keybinding invoked by two keys

Tags: vim, key-bindings

**What I want to do:** How can I create a custom keybinding in vim to write "hello world" while in insert mode, by first holding down 'w' then pressing '2'?

**Note**, I don't want my command invoked by pressing w then 2 -- the w key must be held down then 2 pressed. Note also, that if the 2 key is first held down then w pressed, the command should not be called.

The reason for wanting w to first be held down then pressing 2 is that, if I wanted to type "w2" literally I could do that by pressing+depressing w then pressing 2

Comment: Why must the `w` be held down? This sounds like an Emacs user trying to get out :)

Comment: Ew Emacs! Actually an autohotkey user!

Comment: If it was me, I would forget about the holding down part and use Vim as it is mostly intended (which is to say via key sequences)  Perhaps look into Snipmate with some custom snippets which you can trigger by pressing tab after a specified sequence http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

Comment: I can do the above with the pc program autohotkey while using Vim without any conflicting problems, however there is no good ahk alternative for OsX, so I have to figure out how to do this with just Vim

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski by the way, your comment made me switch to emacs a few months later

Comment: thanks for returning a decade later to let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) or, even better, [TypeIt4Me](http://www.ettoresoftware.com/products/typeit4me/)?

Anyway, the exact mechanism you describe is not possible in Vim in insert mode natively. Since `w` is not a modifier key you can't keep it pressed and expect Vim to register the second keypress.

The closer I could think of is [arpeggio](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425) which lets you map things to *simultaneously pressed keys*.

Comment: Yes, it looks like arpeggio is the closest thing for vim. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

type `:inoreab w2 hello world` or write `inoreab w2 hello world` in your `.vimrc`

then when you are in INSERT mode, type `w2<space>`, the two words will be up there.

leader key (`<leader>`) could be anykey, user can map it by himself. default is `\`.  btw, I don't think it is a good idea to map `w` as leader key. it conflict with `w` (word forward) in normal mode.

I mapped `,` (comma) as leader key.

more detail pls check `:h <leader>`

**EDIT** for OP's comment

> Can I somehow do this without having to press `<space>`?

Yes you can.( However I don't recommend that way.)

you could go mapping way to skip the space.

```
:inoremap w2 hello world
```

note that if you have that mapping, in INSERT mode, anytime you press `w2` "hello world" will be immediately there. I am not sure if it is convenient for you, for me not.